# three dimensional array in c shap

Tags: c#, api, multidimensional-array

I am a c# guy and working with an api where all examples are in php so i need help so i can understand what is this code exactly

```
$rooms = array();

     // First Room
     $rooms[] = array(array("paxType" => "Adult"));

     // Second Room
     $rooms[] = array(array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Child", "age" => 8));
```

I need if anybody can describe this code to me as i am c# guy.

As i am google around this so this is a multidimensional array that i already understand

and pax is class in this api (as per api documentation) which have some properties like paxtype,age etc.....

but i am not getting the way to right this in c#.

**Edit**

that pax type multidimensional array passed to this method

```
public getAvailableHotelResponse getAvailableHotel(string apiKey, string destinationId, DateTime checkIn, DateTime checkOut, string currency, string clientNationality, bool onRequest, pax[][] rooms, filter[] filters);
```

**2nd EDIT**

```
public getAvailableHotelResponse getAvailableHotel(string apiKey, string destinationId, DateTime checkIn, DateTime checkOut, string currency, string clientNationality, bool onRequest, pax[][] rooms, filter[] filters);
```

I have to pass this pax[][] rooms in my method and rooms will have the  following  structure

```
rooms[0][0][paxType]=Adult
rooms[0][1][paxType]=Adult
rooms[0][2][paxType]=Child
rooms[0][2][age]=6


rooms[1][0][paxType]=Adult
rooms[1][1][paxType]=Adult
rooms[1][2][paxType]=Child
rooms[1][2][age]=8
```

and the pax class is below

```
 public class pax
    {
        public pax();

        [SoapElement(DataType = "integer")]
        public string age { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string paxType { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

I think its now much clearer to us all.

Comment: Yes, you've made a multidimensional array. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Utkanos how to right this in c#

Comment: I am a PHP'er not a C guy, my understanding is a multidimensional array in any language is a multidimensional array.

Comment: @Lion yes because example which i have in php and i have to write this code in c#

Comment: i think this question is goinig to close as non constructive and i do not get my answer

Comment: If you know C# create an array where each key value pair is itself an array?

Comment: @Dale thanks i will try and if face any problem edit my question

Comment: It's just like a HashTable that uses a key/value pair.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are dynamic in PHP. Since one cannot determine the size, translating it to C# will require a non-primitive array.

```
// $rooms = array ();
List<List<pax>> rooms = new List<List<pax>>();
```

The ff PHP code,

```
$rooms[] = array (array ("paxType" => "Adult"));
```

can also be interpreted as:

```
$room = array ();
$pax = array ();
$pax["paxType"] = "Adult";
$room[] = $pax;
$rooms[] = $room;
```

Hence,

```
// $room = array ();
List<pax> room = new List<pax>();

// $pax = array ();
pax p = new pax();

// $pax["paxType"] = "Adult";
p.paxType = "Adult";

// $room[] = $pax;
room.Add(p);

// $rooms[] = $room;
rooms.Add(room);
```

Then just convert it to a primitive array.

```
// this will be the pax type array
pax[][] paxRooms = new pax[rooms.count][];
for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Count; i++) {
    paxRooms[i][] = rooms[i].ToArray();
}
```

P.S. I'm a PHP/Java guy so excuse me for syntax errs.

Comment: @its now working for me dear . I just need a pax[][] type array . as you can see in my method signature

Comment: @rahularyansharma what is working? once you have the rooms List then just convert it to a pax array. won't the idea of last code block work?

Comment: i write this code  List<pax> room = new List<pax>();       
        
        pax p1 = new pax();

        p1.paxType="Adult";

        room.Add(p1);

        pax[][] p2 = new pax[room.Count][];

        for (int i = 0; i < room.Count; i++)
        {
            p2[i][] = room[i].ToArray();
        }

Comment: @rahularyansharma What's the problem with that? All that's left is to loop for every room. `foreach (List<pax> room in rooms) { /*your code here */}`

Comment: is it possible to come in chat room

Comment: please check my second edit i think now scene will be more clear to you

Comment: @rahularyansharma Checked. The edits don't seem to affect my translation of PHP to C#.

Comment: i am have made some progress but stil some issues , so going new question as that error is different from this one , i will give you link here so we can move forward

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493120/object-reference-error-in-multi-dimesional-array  please check this

Answer (score -1):

The `$rooms` data structure looks like this:

```
[
  [{paxType:"Adult"}],
  [{paxType:"Adult"}, {paxType:"Adult"}, {paxType:"Child", age:8}]
]
```