# Why do I get an "object reference error" with this multi dimensional array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, nullreferenceexception

Here is my class pax

```
 public class pax
    {
        public pax();

        [SoapElement(DataType = "integer")]
        public string age { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string paxType { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

and i have declare the following array

```
pax[][]rooms=new pax[3][];

        rooms[0][0].paxType = "Adult";
        rooms[0][1].paxType="Adult";
        rooms[0][2].paxType="Child";
        rooms[0][2].age = "6";
```

Its throwing an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  on line

```
 rooms[0][0].paxType = "Adult";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only give you array.

```
pax[][]rooms=new pax[3][];
```

To instantiate object, you have to `new` it:

```
rooms[0][0] = new pax();
```

You might be coming from C++ and may think that object array automatically create all objects, but that's not the case here - you will have to create each one because it is `null` before you do it.

EDIT:

Since you have jagged array here:

```
pax[][]rooms=new pax[3][];
rooms[0]=new pax[3];
rooms[0][0]=new pax();
```

Jagged array = array of arrays.  If you need multidimensional (2-dimensional array), that's different story, and you would say:

```
pax[,] rooms=new pax[3,3];
```

for example...

Comment: pax[][]rooms=new pax[3][];
       rooms[0][0] = new pax();
       rooms[0][0].paxType = "Adult"; but still the same error

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c